# What have I got in my pocket?

Tags: code-golf

> **Synopsis:** Find characters that are enclosed by `MYPOCKET`.

**Example Input**

```
MYPHEIF
YFOCKVH
MBNDEIF
TEUFTMY
ESNDUWP
KBOVUVO
CENWFKC
OPYMTEB
```

**Example Output**

```
F   
BND 
EUF   
SNDUW 
BOVUV 
ENWF
```

Huh? How did we get that as an output? The "pocket" can sometimes be difficult to see. This will make it clearer:

```
MYPHEIF
YFOCKVH
MBNDEIF
TEUFTMY
ESNDUWP
KBOVUVO
CENWFKC
OPYMTEB
```

The letters in bold indicate a ring of characters connected orthogonally to each other consisting of the string `MYPOCKET` repeated over and over again. Your program should output the characters that are within that ring.

Notes:

- There will only be one "pocket".
- Trailing new lines or spaces after lines are allowed.
- The rest of the grid may also contain characters from `MYPOCKET`, but not in a way that makes the shape of the ring ambiguous.
- The `M` is not always in the top-right corner.
- The "pocket" can move in either a clockwise or a counter-clockwise direction.
- The "pocket" won't move in diagonal directions -- that is, each letter is connected left, right, up, or down to the next.

Here's another input you can test your program with.

**Example Input**

```
EKCYMOPD
KCOPHAYM
EKNDSEST
JETHACKE
KRMYPOBN
```

**Example Output**

```
  HA
NDSES
 HA
```

Comment: *What has it got in its nasty little pocketses?*

Comment: Was this inspired by [this challenge](http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?What+have+I+got+in+my++POCKET) from Anarchy Golf?

Comment: @xnor No, it wasn't. (Although it is somewhat similar...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl 5, 414

```pl
map{$y=0;push@{$h{$_}},[$-,$y++]for@$_;$-++}@l=map[/./g],<>;sub n{($a,$b,$c,$d)=@_;$a==$c&&1==abs$b-$d||$b==$d&&1==abs$a-$c}sub c{my($x,$y,$n)=@_;for(grep{($f=defined$x)?n$x,$y,@$_:1}@{$h{(MYPOCKET=~/./g)[$n%8]}}){($m,$l)=@$_ if!$f;return@r=([@$_],@r)if$n>2&&n(@$_,$m,$l)||c(@$_,$n+1)}''}c;$l[$_->[0]][$_->[1]]=$" for@r;($l[$_]=join'',@{$l[$_]})=~s/^(\w+)\s|\s(\w+)$/$"x($1||$2)=~y%%%c/eg for 0..@l;print join$/,@l
```

Usage: save as pocket.pl and run with:

```sh
perl pocket.pl <<< '<grid>'
```

I went for a recursive function to brute-force the path, which might not have been the best, but was the first approach I considered.

Whilst it works for both of the current test cases there are some caveats:

- it includes leading spaces (which I didn't see mentioned in the rules...); and
- it will definitely not work with a 'pocket' that contains characters in the middle (say U shaped or similar).

I want to continue working on this, but wanted to show that there is interest in the question! Happy to document my process if helpful.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2.7 <del>571</del> <del>542</del> 509

```python
import sys
o,l,v,k,w="MYPOCKET",[list(e)for e in sys.stdin],[],enumerate,len
def f(z,q,t):
 for r,c in(z,q+1),(z,q-1),(z+1,q),(z-1,q):
  if w(l)>r>=0 and 0<=c<w(l[r])and o[t]==l[r][c]:
    v.append((r,c))
    if f(r,c,(t+1)%w(o)):return 1
    else:v.pop()
 if z==1 and(0,q)in v or z==0 and(z,q+1)in v:return 1
for i,x in k(l[0]):
 v=[(0,i)]
 if x==o[0]and f(0,i,1):break
for i in range(1,w(l)-1):b=[y for x,y in sorted(v)if x==i];print"".join(["".join(e)if w(e)>0 else" "for e in[l[i][b[j-1]+1:y]for j,y in k(b)][1:]])
```

Works as a program(banking on a recursive function) and accepting input from stdin.
[Demo here.](https://ideone.com/ITDSAc)
Testing it (`ex1.txt` and `ex2.txt` are the examples from the question)-

```
$ python pockets.py < ex1.txt
F
BND
EUF
SNDUW
BOVUV
ENWF
$ python pockets.py < ex2.txt 
  HA 
NDSES
 HA
```

Ungolfed version with comments -

```
s="""
EKCYMOPD
KCOPHAYM
EKNDSEST
JETHACKE
KRMYPOBN
"""
li2=[list(e.strip()) for e in s.split("\n") if e.strip()!='']
buf=[]
def find_precious(row, col, c_ind):
    for r,c in[(row,col+1),(row,col-1),(row+1,col),(row-1,col)]:
        if len(li2)>r>=0 and 0<=c<len(li2[r]) and seq[c_ind]==li2[r][c]:
            if (r,c)in buf:return True
            buf.append((r,c))
            if find_precious(r,c,(c_ind+1)%len(seq)):return True
            else:buf.pop()
    if row==1 and (row-1,col) in buf or row==0 and (row,col+1) in buf:return True
    return False

for i,x in enumerate(li2[0]):
    if x==seq[0]:
        buf=[(0,i)]
        if find_precious(0,i,1):break
if len(buf)==1:
    exit("Failed")

#Calculate the middle men
for i in range(1,len(li2)-1):
    b=[y for x,y in sorted(buf)if x==i]
    print "".join(["".join(e)for e in [li2[i][b[j-1]+1:y]for j,y in enumerate(b)][1:]if len(e)>0])
```

Let me know, if I did something stupid or something can be done better.

I know it's looong, but it's the best I could do :P

Comment: Eh, I'm so bad at Python I'd probably brute-force it //I don't have any knowledge of lambdas in Python...// but nice solution! Still better than none.